# Algorithm that sorts the vertices in a graph by their distance from the source

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have the following question from data structure course, and I would like to know please if my solution is correct.

let G(V,E) be a connected, non-directed graph, such that |V|=m and |E|=n. Every vertex got its unique name (from 1 to n). Now given a source vertex S, I need to sort all the vertices by their distance from S, and print them. Complexity O(m+n)

My solution (theoretical) :

I will basically use BFS pseudo-code, and I will add the following command at the end of the while loop, for example before painting the current vertex 'u' black:

Enqueue(Q2,u).

then I will have a sorted Queue Q2 that I can print.

Do You think its correct?
Many thanks!

Comment: isn't it shortest path algorithm (Dijkstra) from  s to all nodes of your graph ?

Answer (score 0):

If your edges are cost-weighted, then you will need to use Dijkstra's algorithm instead of breadth-first. Otherwise, yeah, that method is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you described is solved by [Dijkstra algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). It basically takes the closest not yet visited node and writes down the distance to all nodes closest to it:

```
1. start from the source node S
2. add all neighboring nodes into a list, ordered by their distance 
   and write down the current shortest distance to them
3. pick the closest node N
4. update the distances of all already visited nodes, if a shorter distance
   is available to them through N
5. add remaining neighboring nodes into the list
6. eliminate N from the list and repeat from step 3.
```

It is imperative, that you visit the nodes in the order from the closest one to the most distant, so that you don't miss any possible shortest path.

The challenge in implementing Dijkstra is the implementation of priority front, which stores the nodes, ordered by their distance from the source. If you use a simple list, you also need to account for the input of a new node into the array, as correct position of element needs to be found.

Therefore there are multiple improvements over basic Dijkstra, for example using [Fibonacci heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap) as a structure for implementing priority queue.